# Most elegant way to save only primitive properties of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, recursion, underscore.js

I have an object with lots of own and inherited methods. I need to make a simple snapshot of it with only primitive properties.

What's the most elegant way how to do it?

Javascript snippet

```
function copy(source) {
    var target;
    if (source) {
        target = {};
        for (var key in source) {
            var prop = source[key],
                type = typeof prop;
            if (type === "string" || type === "number" || type === "boolean") {
                target[key] = prop;
            }
            if (type == "object") {
                target[key] = copy(prop);
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

With [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
function copy(source) {
    var target;
    if (source) {
        target = {};
        _.filter( _.keys(source), function( key ) {
            var prop = source[key];
            if (!_.isFunction(prop) && !_.isObject(prop)) {
                target[key] = prop;
            }
            if (_.isObject(prop)) {
                target[key] = copy(prop);
            }
        });
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried to do ?

Comment: Would `JSON.stringify` suit your requirements for a "snapshot"?

Comment: probably, that is what I was thinking about aswell..

Comment: When you say "only primitive properties" do you mean only properties which are not functions but which come from anywhere on the prototype chain? Or are you only interested in properties unique to the current type?

Comment: @lauromine I've added my snippet

Comment: @Max Bumaye I have circular reference in this object

Comment: Propably you are seeing the representation of the object by firefox/chrome console or firebug.

Comment: @glenatron yes, only properties which are not functions but which come from anywhere on the prototype chain, my main task is to compare this snapshots in order to undo/redo actions..

Comment: @naoxink :) no, I have lots of custom setters and getters in this object

Comment: @francesca maybe `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source))` helps you :)

Comment: I think how you have done it is in some way elegant enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are dealing with a mix of types that may or may not be what you want thanks to the loose typing that JavaScript offers. Specifically without walking any given array it is impossible to tell whether it only contains primitives and you might therefore want to keep it or whether it contains objects or functions that you want to filter out.

I realise library recommendations are the oldest hat, but I'm also going to strongly recommend that you use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ( or a derivative such as [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) ) which gives a whole lot of super-convenient functions that I use the whole time. In a very real sense these feel like the missing part of the core JavaScript language - in fact in some cases they are wrapping native functionality, but allowing you to avoid platform inconsistencies.

If you have Underscore included in your library then you can find the non-object property names of any given object like this:

```
var myObject = { 
   a: "hello",
   b: "goodbye",
   c: function() { console.log(this.b);}
   d: { hello: "banana" }
};

_.filter( _.keys(myObject), function( key ) { 
        return ! _.isObject(myObject[key]);
}) // => ["a", "b"]
```

This could then be tidied into a function to clone the object, but of course it's unnecessary because Underscore offers us `_.pick`, which returns a copy of the object with only the whitelisted properties:

```
_.pick( myObject, _.filter( _.keys(myObject), function( key ) { return ! _.isObject(myObject[key]);}))
```

By flipping the `!_.isObject` you can retrieve all the properties which are objects, and perform a similar mapping on those if necessary. By wrapping both in a function you can call it recursively on the child objects you want to clone.

This answers your question, but be aware that this might not be the best way to perform undo/redo actions, which you mention in your comments is the use you plan to put this to. It may be easier to record actions and states onto a history stack recording only the actual changes any action performs, where they can be retrieved and reverted safely without needing to keep snapshots of your data.